# Receiving error on attempt to overload operator on string

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I know this can be done in C++, but I'm not sure what to look for with this. Basically I have a `string` value in a custom class named `Priority`. What I would like to do is add a custom operator to allow `Priority++` or `Priority--` in which a few things happen. The operation would look like this...

```
public static -- ()
{
    Int32 priority = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    priority--;
    string returnValue = priority.ToString();
    return returnValue;
}
```

and the opposite for `++`. What I have can be found below, however I receive the error `Priority is a property, but is used like a type.`

Existing erred code:

```
public static Priority operator ++(string value)
{
    Int32 priority = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    priority--;
    string returnValue = priority.ToString();
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Why priority class holds string if it has to be a number?

Comment: Why dont you just make it a int?

Answer (score 1):

take a step back and consider :

```
int i = 0;
i++;
```

the `++` operator here takes an int, and returns an updated int.

I have a simple class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }

    public static MyClass operator ++(MyClass myclass)
    {
        myclass.Test += " test";
        return myclass;
    }
}
```

the ++ operator takes a `MyClass` and returns an updated `MyClass`.

Your `++` operator needs to take a `Priority` object and return an updated `Priority` object, what gets updated is up to you.

Comment: Also `++` operator shouldn't mutate the object. It should return new one.